# How to implement Random Forest with a lot of categorical columns?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I want to implement a random forest to predict which customers will be a 'goner' and which customers will be a 'stayer'.

I have data for customers who already left or are still there (it's just my imagination no real customer data).

Now I have a couple of columns that look like this:

```
CustomerNR | Email (Y/N) | Age   | Water Usage (in l) | How did we Contact them?
1          | Yes         | 20-30 | 1000l              | Mail
2          | No          | 50-70 | 500l               | Telephone
3          | Yes         | 40-50 | 1099l              | NAN
```

How would I start with this?
I really am inexperienced and don't find the tutorials online helpful because they are always on stuff with numbers like weather predictions etc.

I have 200k "Customers" in my Dataset and wanted to know if there is a good tutorial for this or at least some directions where i could go.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Be lazy and use the awesome [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org). [Here's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_ensemble_oob.html) the official documentation on the topic of implementing it. If you're a ML beginner, I'd suggest that you should focus more on the data 'wrangling' part, otherwise, Random Forest implementation with scikit is just 1 or 2 lines!

Comment: @DaveIdito ... but categorical features have to be one-hot encoded